# Scoping rule - let keyword - TypeScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the below sample code,

```
let a: number = 1; // Global(G)
function f(){
    // let a: number = 1; // Enclosing(E)
    return function g(){
        // let a: number = 1;  // Local(L)
        return a;
    }
}

console.log(f()());
```

---

Does `let` keyword follow LEGB rule for variable lookup, similar to python?

Comment: The identifier `a` is not resolved differently because it was declared with `let`. The only difference between `let` and `var` (wrt scope resolution) is that `let` allows to declare variables in block scopes.

Comment: @Bergi  First try using `const`, otherwise use `let`. Do not use `var`. This is the rule I follow. There is no chance to understand, how `var` works? All `var` keywords should be replaced with `let` in existing application

Comment: NO - Javascript is not Python - please learn the scoping rules of the language(s) you are asking about.

Comment: @RandyCasburn But I see the above TypeScript code works according to  LEGB rule.

Comment: @overexchange No, it doesn't follow any complicated four-letter-rule. It just uses lexical scoping - there are no exceptions. The global scope just encloses all scope chains, and all builtins are defined in the global scope.

Comment: @Bergi How different is LEGB from lexical scoping? It is same, because, every inner level can access its outer levels.

Comment: @overexchange If it's not different, why would you need to give it a separate name?

Comment: @Bergi Agreed. But I learnt that `let` uses lexical scoping after reading this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005678/scoping-rule-let-keyword-typescript-javascript?noredirect=1#comment87028291_50005678). Your referred question doesn't help answer this.

Comment: @overexchange Everything uses lexical scope in JS. It doesn't matter what keyword the variable was declared with - `var`,`let`, `const`, `function`, … - only in what scope it is.

Comment: @Bergi `var` does not follow lexical scoping. See the [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) where `f` has parameter `shouldInitialize`. In this function `f`, `return x` is referring to inner level declaration(`var x = 10`).

Comment: @overexchange `x` still is **looked up** using lexical scoping rules. Sure, `var` does declare the variable in the function scope, but that is not what you were asking about.

Comment: @Bergi Lexical scoping rule, says, every inner level can access its outer level, unlike the example function(`f`)

Comment: @overexchange Even in that example, the outer level does not access the inner level. `var` declares a variable in the function level despite being inside the block level, but still the variable is accessed as usual.

Comment: @Bergi With `var` keyword, semantically yes, but syntactically no. This is why I use `let` keyword that syntactically/semantically show/follow lexical scoping. This makes a lot of difference, in debugging problem code. This is why, I do not prefer reading your referred question that talks about `var` keyword.

Comment: @overexchange So is there anything left unclear?

Comment: @Bergi In this syntax `function f(x) {}`. Is `x`, `var` declared or `let` declared? Yes, `x` is function scoped variable

Comment: @overexchange Neither, it's declared as a function parameter?